# parameter type documentation for pdb.file_png_save2

Tags: gimp, python-fu

Error message from gimp - pdb.file_png_save2(...)
(wrong parameter type)  - parameters seem to follow doc but still gives error...

In a plug-in/script module I am trying to save a .png file.  I am using
pdb.file_png_save2() because I need to preserve transparency.  I am getting nowhere.  The following is from the python-fu console.

```
>>> img=gimp.image_list()[0]
>>> lyr=img.layers[0]
>>> pdb.file_png_save2(img, lyr, "/tmp/untitled14.png", "untitled14.png", False, 9, False, False, False, False, False, "", True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: wrong parameter type
```

And just to verify that the objects are valid --->

```
>>> img
<gimp.Image 'I230112341bgsl.jpg'>
>>> lyr
<gimp.Layer 'Background'>
>>>
```

So, which parameter is wrong type. And if so where is there any real documentation (ie not from the pdb browser 'explanation' - because that is obviously insufficient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `comment` (next to last) should be a Boolean (type INT32 in the documentation...). It is not the comment itself, but tells if the image comment (from `Image>Properties`) is written.

The PDB is usually sufficient. Of course it is generated from the docs more meant for script-fu but the mappings are reasonably consistent.

Comment: Of course!   I have no idea why after staring at the pdb database for ages, my eyes missed that. Danke!

Comment: I ended up using trying the alternative of doing the save in two steps.  1) pdb.file_png_set_defaults() and then 2) pdb.file_png_save_defaults()